# How to update ListView with socket.io data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working in React Native and fetch data like normal from an API then generate a ListView with it. This works great. Then I use socket.io to get updated trade data. This also works and I then have tradeMsg which is an object with the data in it that matches what the dataSource objects look like. The problem comes when I try to update the dataSource so that the ListView will dynamically update the one part that matches the tradeMsg. Any ideas here on what the code should look like? Here is my code (I marked the part that probably need adjusting):

```js
  componentDidMount() {

//Socket.io part
    const socket = io.connect('http://socket.coincap.io', {transports: ['websocket']})

    socket.on('trades', function(tradeMsg) {
      //This part probably needs adjusting
      let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.setState({
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(tradeMsg)
        });
        console.log('updated');
    }.bind(this));



//Normal API fetch part
    return fetch('http://www.coincap.io/front')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
        }, function() {
          // do something with new state
           console.log('basic api called')
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an error message or just not the behaviour you're expecting?

Comment: My list view turns from 600 parts long to just 1 empty one. My attempt is clearly very wrong. I think I somehow need to go in and edit the data in dataSource but don't know how

Comment: If the answer below isn't what you're after, it would be a good idea to comment appropriately on it, or expand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `.cloneWithRows()` a complete dataset each time -- it will do a diff using your `rowHasChanged` function to determine which rows to change.

So in your fetch you will do something like `this.data = response.json` before the `cloneWithRows` call. Then in the socket listener, you will create a clone of this.data** with the incoming object either added to the cloned array (if it's new) or replacing the updated object (if it's an update). Then call `cloneWithRows()` with the new array, and keep a reference to it.

** a clone because the React Native ListViewDataSource doesn't make a copy of the data blob passed to `cloneWithrows`, so you don't want to mutate it

Comment: By the way you might also want to experiment with [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) which is apparently more performant, and the API is simpler. Updating or adding to the FlatList is just a matter of assigning an array to the lists .data prop.